# DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have made a freeze command using discord.js and commando, that gives the user a role, and keeps them from talking and chatting. It seems that every time I run it though, it tosses an error:

```
(node:7352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
```

I haven't been able to find what it is, but maybe i'm just a nub.

Code:

```js
async run(message, { user }) {
  message.delete()

  const member = message.guild.member(user);

  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.say("Sorry, but you do not have the Mute Members Permission! If you beleive this is a error, contact an owner.");

  if (!user) return message.say(`Cannot find user!`)

  if (member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.say("The user you are trying to freeze is either the same, or higher role than you.");

  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "Frozen");

  if (member.roles.has(muterole)) return message.say(`${user.username} is already frozen!`);

  if (!muterole) {
    try {
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "Frozen",
        color: "#000000",
        permissions: []
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async(channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          SPEAK: false
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
    }

    await (member.addRole(muterole.id))
    message.say(`**${user.username} has been frozen! To unfreeze them, use the unfreeze command!**`)
    message.delete(5000)
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You first delete the message and then grab everything from there? Doesn't seem right..

Answer (score 4):

I think that's caused by the fact that you're deleting the message with `message.delete()` in the first lines, but at the end you do that again with `message.delete(5000)`.
The rest of the code runs fine because even if you deleted the message it's still saved in your `message` variable, but when you try to delete that again the API isn't able to find it. Try removing one of the `message.delete()`