# Custom discordgame runs fine the 1st time but messes up the 2nd time

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a custom game in discord. It grabs words from a list of words in the scramble-words.json file and scrambles them. Those words get put into a text chat and the user playing the game has to try and find what the actual word is. It'll delete all new messages that get sent since you started the game and keep the channel clean as long as the game is active. You have to type the word and if it's correct you get a point.

The first time the command is run the code runs fine. The second time it gives an error
 `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message` with every message you send in the new game.

I've tried looking up if it had to do something with me assigning the `games = {}` variable as a const but I don't think that's the problem and I can't think of what else it could be.

```
const { words } = require('./scramble-words.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

/*const example = {

    channelId: {

        message:'message object',
        stage: 'string',
        counter: 'number',
        currentWord: 'string',
        remainingWords: ['words here'],
        points: {
            userId: 'points'
        }

    }

}*/

const games = {}

const stages = {

    'STARTING': (counter, topic) => {

        return `-----------------------------**Game**------------------------------\nA new "${topic} Scramble" game is starting in ${counter}s!`

    },

    'IN_GAME': (word, topic) => {

        let scrambledWord = '';

        if(topic === "Brawlhalla"){
            topic = "Brawlhalla related thing"
        }

        scrambledWord = shuffle(word);

        return `-----------------------------**Game**------------------------------\nWhat ${topic} is this?\n\n **${scrambledWord}**`

    },

    'ENDING': (points) => {

        const sorted = Object.keys(points).sort((a, b) => {

            return points[b] - points[a]

        })
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle('**POINTS**')
            .setDescription(`**The game is now over! Here's how everyone did!**`);

        var results = `\n`

        var firstPlace = points[sorted[0]]
        var secondPlace = null
        var thirdPlace = null
        var leftover = null

        for(const key of sorted) {

            var amount = points[key]

            if(leftover){

                results += `<@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`

            } else if(thirdPlace) {

                if(thirdPlace === amount) {

                    results += `:third_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`

                } else {

                    results += `\n`
                    results += `<@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
                    leftover = amount

                }

            } else if(secondPlace) {

                if(secondPlace === amount) {

                    results += `:second_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`

                } else {

                    results += `\n`
                    results += `:third_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
                    thirdPlace = amount

                }
    
            } else if(firstPlace) {
             
                if(firstPlace === amount) {

                    results += `:first_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
                
                } else {

                    results += `\n`
                    results += `:second_place: <@${key}> had ${amount} point${amount === 1 ? '' : 's'}\n`
                    secondPlace = amount
                
                }
    
            }

        }

        if(results === `\n`){

            return embed.setTimestamp().addField(`**Nobody got points you losers**`, "");

        } else {

            return embed.setTimestamp().addField(`**Here's how everyone did**`, results)

        }

    }

}

const selectWord = (game) => {

    game.currentWord = game.remainingWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * game.remainingWords.length)]

    const index = game.remainingWords.indexOf(game.currentWord);
    game.remainingWords.splice(index, 1);
    
    game.currentWord = game.currentWord.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + game.currentWord.toLowerCase().substring(1);

}

const gameLoop = async () => {

    for(const key in games) {

        const game = games[key];
        const { message, stage } = game;

        const gameLength = 2.345

        if(stage === 'STARTING') {

            let string = stages[stage](game.counter, game.topic)
            message.edit(string)

            if(game.counter <= 0) {

                game.stage = 'IN_GAME'
                game.counter = 60 * gameLength

                selectWord(game)
    
                string = stages[game.stage](game.currentWord, game.topic)
                message.edit(string)
    
            }

        } else if (stage === 'IN_GAME') {

            if(game.counter <= 0) {

                game.stage = 'ENDING'

                if(game.topic === "Brawlhalla")
                {
                    game.topic === "Brawlhalla related thing"
                    
                }

                const string = `-----------------------------**Game**------------------------------\nThe last ${game.topic} was: ${game.currentWord}\n------------------------------**End**-------------------------------`

                message.edit(string)
                embed = stages[game.stage](game.points);
                message.channel.send(embed)

                await delete games[key]
                await delete game

                return

            }

        }

        --game.counter

    }

    setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000)
    
}

module.exports = {

    scramble(member, channel, content, guild, message, { reply }, client) {

        /*if(!member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){

            reply(true, `You don't have permission to execute this command!`)
            return;

        }*/

        if(channel.name !== "scramble-games" && channel.name !== "games"){
            
            reply(true, `You can only do this command in a channel called "scramble-games" or "games"`);
            return;

        }

        if(games[channel.id]){

            return;

        }

        message.delete();

        var chosenCategory= []

        if(content[0]){

            if(content[0].toLowerCase() === "pokemon"){

                if(content[1]){

                    var numbers = content[1].split('')

                    if(!isNaN(content[1])){

                        for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){

                            if(numbers[i] === "1") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration1)

                            } else if(numbers[i] === "2") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration2)

                            } else if(numbers[i] === "3") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration3)
                                
                            } else if(numbers[i] === "4") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration4)
                                
                            } else if(numbers[i] === "5") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration5)
                                
                            } else if(numbers[i] === "6") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration6)
                                
                            } else if(numbers[i] === "7") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration7)
                                
                            } else if(numbers[i] === "8") {

                                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration8)
                                
                            } else {

                                reply(true, `The numbers you gave had a number that is higher than 8. There are only 8 gens. Try again but keep the numbers you give under 8`)
                                return;

                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        reply(true, `If you want to specify gens you have to give numbers only! example: 1456 will give gens 1, 4, 5 and 6`)
                        return;

                    }

                } else {

                    chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(pokemonGeneration1, pokemonGeneration2, pokemonGeneration3, pokemonGeneration4, pokemonGeneration5, pokemonGeneration6, pokemonGeneration7, pokemonGeneration8)

                }

                topics = "Pokemon"
    
            } else if (content[0].toLowerCase() === "brawlhalla" || content[0].toLowerCase() === "brawl"){
    
                chosenCategory = chosenCategory.concat(BrawlhallaLegends, BrawlhallaWeapons, BrawlhallaWords, BrawlhallaColors, BrawlhallaStances, BrawlhallaChests, BrawlhallaGamemodes)
                topics = "Brawlhalla"
    
            } else {

                reply(true, `That's not a valid topic for this game!`);
                return

            }

        } else {

            chosenCategory = words
            topics = "Random Word"
            
        }

        channel.send('Preparing Game...').then((message) => {

            games[channel.id] = {

                message,
                stage: 'STARTING',
                counter: 10,
                remainingWords: [...chosenCategory],
                points: {},
                topic: topics

            }

        });

        gameLoop(channel)

        client.on('message', message => {

            const { channel, content, member } = message;
            const { id } = channel

            const game = games[id];

            if(game && game.currentWord && !member.user.bot) {

                checkWord(game, member, message, content);

            }

            if (game && !message.author.bot) {
                message.delete();
            }

            return;

        });

    }

}

function checkWord(game, member, message, content){

    if(game.stage === 'IN_GAME' && content.toLowerCase() === game.currentWord.toLowerCase()) {

        const owo = game.currentWord;
        game.currentWord = null;
        const seconds = 3;

        const { points } = game
        points[member.id]  = points[member.id] || 0

        message.reply(`You got it!\n The correct answer was: **${owo}**\n +1 point (${++points[member.id]} total)`).then(newMessage => {

            newMessage.delete({

                timeout: 1000 * seconds
            
            });

        });

        setTimeout(() => {

            if(game.stage === 'IN_GAME') {

                selectWord(game)

                const string = stages[game.stage](game.currentWord, game.topic)
                game.message.edit(string);

            }

        }, 1000 * seconds);

    }

}

function shuffle(word) {

    var wordArray = word.split(' ');
    var output = []

    for(var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {

        var array = wordArray[i].split('');

        var currentIndex = array.length;
        var temporaryValue;
        var randomIndex;
  
        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  
            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
  
            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;

        }

        output = output.concat(array)

        if(!i + 1 === wordArray.length){

            output.push(' ');
        
        }

    }
  
    return output.join('');

}
```

Here's the json file too so you can try out the game yourself

```
{
    
    "words": [

        "Provincial",
        "Grudge",
        "Foundation",
        "Carry",
        "Fight",
        "Belt",
        "Perforate",
        "Obstacle",
        "Hide",
        "Lesson",
        "Car",
        "Building",
        "Mourning",
        "Debut",
        "Sunrise",
        "Scatter",
        "Clash",
        "Equation",
        "Performer",
        "Ask",
        "Butterfly",
        "Medieval",
        "Think",
        "Minimum",
        "Play",
        "Sofa",
        "Minority",
        "Friend",
        "Protect",
        "Mess",
        "Disability",
        "Planet",
        "Federation",
        "Film",
        "Vegetarian",
        "Utter",
        "Polish",
        "Ankle",
        "Calendar",
        "Extreme",
        "Student",
        "Barrier",
        "Motif",
        "Solo",
        "Toast",
        "Steel",
        "Speaker",
        "Concede",
        "Suit",
        "gimping",
        "Weal",
        "Affords",
        "Palship",
        "Trefoil",
        "Kirtled",
        "Jaybirds",
        "Shires",
        "Gobbling",
        "Puffery",
        "Bag",
        "Idoneous",
        "Aerates",
        "Kitchens",
        "Zorils",
        "Students",
        "Idles",
        "Howe",
        "Veenas",
        "Airship",
        "Olefins",
        "Munsters",
        "Polemics",
        "Lentos",
        "Snog",
        "Fusel",
        "Giglot",
        "Pinafore",
        "Snowiest",
        "Saxtuba",
        "Division",
        "Mantlet",
        "Nurtures",
        "Geoponic",
        "Civvies",
        "Trommels",
        "Engraver",
        "Know",
        "Gummoses",
        "Disbands",
        "Parse",
        "Donator",
        "Minces",
        "Lofted",
        "Punters",
        "Lie",
        "Rune",
        "Dottiest",
        "Mib",
        "Enwraps",
        "Bizzes",
        "Nitride",
        "Ire",
        "Bricole",
        "Bigness",
        "Roadeos",
        "Midriffs",
        "Fallers",
        "Postcode",
        "Sterigma",
        "Duvetyne",
        "Alumroot",
        "Purins",
        "Pricking",
        "Deluders",
        "Postcoup",
        "Daggas",
        "Rallies",
        "Vocably",
        "Gravida",
        "Eluded",
        "Dicyclic",
        "Starers",
        "Afflatus",
        "Misbind",
        "Coadmire",
        "Overrule",
        "Marquis",
        "Pogromed",
        "Dulled",
        "Lantana",
        "Garotte",
        "Keek",
        "Dhak",
        "Mescals",
        "Trichite",
        "Theurgic",
        "Cretins",
        "Codicils",
        "Depside",
        "Cadres",
        "Desium",
        "Indene",
        "Depicted",
        "Opticist",
        "Hoptoad",
        "Jacking",
        "Girasole",
        "Wedeln",
        "Pull"

    ]

}
```

Comment: These API errors occur most often when you delete a message then try and fetch that message, I can see a few `message#delete()` methods in there that could be the cause

Answer (score 0):

Unknown message errors occur when you delete a message, then try and fetch that message, or use it in a method. I can see 2 `message#delete` methods in your code, and these is nearly always that cause of these errors. Go through your code and find where you are deleting the messages, and make sure you are not using anything to do with that message afterwards. The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536834/discordapierror-unknown-message) displays how these errors occur.

I can see one reason this error would throw, if you are iterating through the games, you use `message#delete` in the first game and the program runs fine, then in all of the other iterations it throws that error. This is because the `message#delete` is trying to delete an already deleted message (i.e. when you first deleted it in the first game).

Comment: I went through and I don't see anything wrong with it. I've asked this same question on a coding help discord somewhere and they gave the exact same response you did so I think I might just not understand what it is you're saying? 

The only 2 message#delete's that I see is the one where you delete the command and than a bit later the one that deletes when a new message gets sent in the client. 

After the game is done it startsover again and would do the exact same thing no?

Comment: As the game iterates, the `message#delete` func is not updated, and so it tries to delete the same message twice, thus throwing the API error

Comment: sorry I still don't understand. We're talking now about the `message.delete()` in the gameloop function right? How exactly is it not updated? I thought the `delete game` would make sure the message from the previous game would also be deleted?

Comment: No, if I'm honest I dont really know what the `delete game` func does. But it wont delete the previous messages from the other games.

Comment: so does that mean I need to find out a way to stop the `client.on, ('message', message => {})` and restart it once a new game starts? if so I have no clue how to do this

Comment: you cant stop the `client on` without restarting the bot, but the problem is in the iteration of the functions, not the `client on`

Comment: Do you have any idea on how  to fix the iteration issue? I thought I would properly stop it with the return once game doesn't exist anymore?